# Constrained MLE of multivariate normal

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

this might be obvious one but I have spent much time without gaining anything.

If $\underline{X}$~$N_p(\underline{\mu},\sigma^2 I)$, where $\mu$ is known to lie on the unit sphere ($\mu^T\mu$), show that the mle of $\mu$ is $\frac{x}{(x^Tx)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

I tried to use "trace trick" of the multi normal mle but could not find it properly..It would be very appreciated if you could give me any hints on this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing a [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$, your goal is to maximize the lagrangian
$$
  \Lambda = \log\,(\text{Likelihood}) + \lambda(\mu^\top\mu-1) \,
$$
Derivative with respect to the vector $\mu$ gives
$$
  \mu = \frac{1}{1+2\lambda} x \, .
$$
Derivative with respect to $\lambda$ gives the constraint
$$
  \mu^\top\mu=1 \, .
$$
Hence,
$$
  \mu^\top\mu = \left(\frac{1}{1+2\lambda}\right)^2 x^\top x = 1 \, ,
$$
and
$$
  \frac{1}{1+2\lambda} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^\top x}} \, ,
$$
which yields the constrained MLE
$$
  \hat{\mu} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^\top x}} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. But, I haven't imagined this way. I guess I missed something during my class. So, shall this Lagrange multiplier be used for optimizing solutions when it has constraints?

Comment: Yes, it's the standard tool. One suggestion: compute the MLE for the multinominal model. It's easy and clarifying. Again, you will introduce one Lagrange multiplier for the constraint that the parameters add up to one.